# Update Style/Remove Attribute

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I need remove style attribute of a div

Line 85
https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/blob/master/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html

```
::content > [condensed-title] {
        pointer-events: none;
        @apply(--layout-flex)*;
      }
```

*(I don't wanna apply flexbox to [condensed-title] in a espefic head component I had made)

Line 133 https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/iron-flex-layout.html

```
    --layout-flex: {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0.000000001px;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 0.000000001px;
  flex-basis: 0.000000001px;
};
```

My code

```
<app-toolbar>
        <div class="logo-title">
          <iron-icon icon="custom-icons:casinha"></iron-icon>
        </div>
        <div id="outAlert" condensed-title>
          <paper-icon-button icon="card-membership"></paper-icon-button>
        </div>
        <div class="sublogo-title">
          <h4>Sublogo</h4>
        </div>
      </app-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem using following code:

```
      #outAlert{
        @apply(--layout-flex-none);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in 3 three ways

- You can style `#outAlert` in your element and set `flex: 0`. This will overwrite app-layout's styling.

  ```
  #outerAlert {
      flex: 0;
  }
  ```
- Use inline style to overwrite flex and set it to 0

  ```
   <div id="outAlert" condensed-title style="flex:0">
  ```
- And lastly overwrite the `--layout-flex` mixin for the `app-layout` where you don't want flex to be there.

  ```
  app-layout {
     --layout-flex: {
        flex: 0; /* You can have any other value also. Not sure if empty mixin will work or not */
     };
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, your ideias were very helpful.